# Menubar hidding div when using anchor linking

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I use Bootstrap and I have a fixed menubar at the top. I add a padding-top on my body in order to display properly the div.

```
body {
    padding-top: 80px;
}
```

Everything is ok but, when I try to navigate with anchors there's no padding anymore and my div is partially hidden.

You can find an example on this JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/TUy7C/

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle or live example?

Comment: where you needed the padding and why..?

Comment: When I use the menubar I want to display all the div, but actually a part of it is hidden by the menubar. Example with JSFiddle : when I click on "home" i loose the first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply the padding to each of the sections instead of the body, and then add a negative bottom margin to close the gap between sections:

http://jsfiddle.net/TUy7C/2/

```
#home, #about, #contact {
    padding-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: -80px;
}
```

Comment: I thought about this solution, but I don't want to "padding" my "about" and "contact" sections all the time (in my website I don't want all this space between sections).

Comment: edited my answer to include a negative bottom-margin. check it out.